# Action Script advice needed!

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to add the following script in my action script for redirecting to first frame after the external video finish,

But I'm not sure how to customize the code that suitable for my sction script.

This is the code I want to add with my AS :

```
ns.onStatus = function(info:Object)
{
if(info.code == 'NetStream.Play.Stop')
{
gotoAndPlay(2);
}
}
```

The following one is the original code now I'm using to play external video files. I need to customize the above code that should be usable for the below one.

```
function checkTime(flv)
{
    var _loc2 = flv.playheadTime;
    var _loc3 = Math.floor(_loc2 / 60);
    var _loc1 = Math.floor(_loc2 % 60);
    if (_loc1 < 10)
    {

        _loc1 = "0" + _loc1;
    } // end if

    current_time.text = _loc3 + ":" + _loc1;
} // End of the function
flv.pauseButton = pause_btn;
flv.playButton = play_btn;
flv.FLVPlayback.align = center;
var time_interval = setInterval(checkTime, 500, flv);

ffwd_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    flv.seek(flv.playheadTime + 2);
};
rewind_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    flv.seek(flv.playheadTime - 5);
};
mute_btn.onRelease = function ()
{
    if (videoSound.getVolume() == 0)
    {
        videoSound.start();
        videoSound.setVolume(volLevel);
    }
    else
    {
        volLevel = _root.videoSound.getVolume();
        videoSound.setVolume(0);
        videoSound.stop();
    } // end else if
};
var videoSound = new Sound(this);
videoSound.setVolume(100);
flv.contentPath = flvurl;
fl.video.FLVPlayback.align = center;
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using AS2, and the `complete` event firing is inconsistent with the FLVPlayback component in AS2 AND you are already polling with `setInterval`, just compare the video `duration` to the `playheadTime` in you `checkTime()` function like so:

```
function checkTime()
{
    // you other stuff here....

    if( flv.metadata && flv.metadata.duration > 0)
    {
        var prog:Number = Math.round((flv.playheadTime/flv.metadata.duration)*100);

        if( prog == 100 )
        {
            //clean up your interval
            clearInterval(time_interval);

            // do 'end of video' stuff
            gotoAndPlay(2);
        }
    }
}
```

note that the `duration` is nested inside the `metadata` property of the `FLVPlayback` instance. It's not available until enough of the flv file has loaded, but since you are polling with your interval, it will be there when you need it.

should get ya what ya want...

Comment: Thank You "GTHMB" for your quick reply, anyway I'll try it soon and let you know how it works!!! Thanks again.

Comment: It dosen't play the video after placing the above code you mentioned.!!!! bad luck :(

Comment: you are just augmenting your current `checkTime()` function with the logic in my example, right? adding the the progress checking should not break playback...

Comment: Yes you're right I just added the same code you mentioned above. But I dont know what happend to the video playing functionality!

Comment: hmm... i wonder if you are hitting a divide by zero error or something... ill update the answer with a check for a valid duration before trying to determine the prog.